# Revert Mercurial repository on buildserver

Tags: version-control, mercurial

Our buildserver has a Mercurial repository. The build cycle starts every hour. Before the cycle starts, any old files have to be deleted: for example, all `obj` and `bin` directories created by the previous build.

To accomplish this, I currently delete the checked out files:

1. Delete every directory except `.hg`
2. Run `hg pull`
3. Run `hg update --clean`

Is there a way to "revert" a Mercurial repository to its "unmodified" state, removing files and directories that are not under version control?

Comment: Personally I would set up an automated build server to handle this stuff for you. There's plenty that are freely available, easy to use, and solve these problems (and many more!) much better than a script.

Comment: @glowcoder: We used CruiseControl at one point, but despite putting quite a lot of effort in it, never got it to work reliably.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [Purge](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/PurgeExtension) extension, I believe.  It can be enabled by adding these lines to `Mercurial.ini`:

```
[extensions]
hgext.purge=
```

And then issue a simple `hg purge`.

---

And even without the extension, you could `pull`, `update --clean`, then capture the output of `hg status`, deleting any paths with a `?` before them.